# SpacePilot Pro 3D Connexion

Tags: customization, shortcut, navigation, mouse, 3d-mouse

I am completely puzzled with the **Space PilotPro 3Dconnexion**. Whilst I have CADMouse pro by the same company, the same works perfectly fine. However, on my 2.83.9 the Space Pilot Pro stopped working in rotation. Pan and zoom work (???!!!!) I have tested it on the 2.91 and it works fine - panning, zooming, orbiting or rotating. I have tried Blender 2.83 to reset to factory setting but it does not help. Also, the auxiliary buttons do not work except when I use setup inside the keyboard setup Preference 3D view. Previously 3D connexion control menu has been working for setting up special functions assigned specific buttons. And it worked like a charm with CAD Mouse Pro but it does no longer with the Space Pilot Pro. Can you someone help me who had a similar issue? Thank you!!!!

[Prefere[image]nce][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oST1y.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]